# Different trace/space rules for copper pour than for traces?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I recently ordered a 4/4 mil trace/space board from a new manufacturer who is geared towards very low-cost prototype manufacturing. They manufactured the first board I sent them with no issues.

However, when I sent them a revision of this board (also 4/4 mil trace/space), they complained that "the spacing between the traces and the nearby copper plane is less than 6 mils; this may cause a short circuit.". They asked me to increase the spacing between the traces and the copper pour to 6 mils. On the very same board, they have no problem with 4 mil spacing between traces. A discussion of distance between traces and ground pour (as opposed to trace/space) is nowhere in their design rules.

**My questions:**

- Why would there be a differentiation between trace/trace spacing and trace/polygon spacing?
- Is this a normal thing for manufacturers to ask for?

I've ordered boards with less than 6/6 mil t/s from other manufacturers and nobody else has differentiated between the spacing between 2 traces and the spacing between a trace and a ground pour.

I asked their customer service about this and they haven't been able to give me a good response, probably because it's such a low-cost place. I realize that the only way to get an answer for this specific manufacturer is for me to talk with them - but I don't think that will happen. I'm asking about whether this is a wider industry practice, not about my specific situation.

Comment: It sounds like someone wasn't paying attention on that first order, and you got away with it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and that's the conclusion I would've ended up with, but I've never heard of "clearance to pour" being different than "clearance between traces" and I couldn't dig up anything online about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that copper pours may presents very sharp angles or long and very thin shapes which may not be terminated properly and end closer to signal trace than expected.
In theory that shouldn't happen but maybe they have some guidelines or had experienced defects with poorly poured copper areas.